# Add audio in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I want to insert the audio to my project and it don't stop when I navigate to the other page. So I can't use MediaElement. What shold I do? please help me.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MediaPlayer instead.

First, add next statements to your code file:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
```

Then add next code where you want to play the audo. Change the Uri string with the one for your file:

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
Song song = Song.FromUri("SongName", new Uri("SongURI", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); // Change with your audio file URI
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

The audio will keep playing if you navigate to other page, but will stop if you quit the app.